# How to detect from cloud code if any changes have been made to my class in Parse cloud

Tags: parse-platform

I want to deploy a cloud service which tracks whether any changes have been made to any of my classes in my app in Parse cloud. How should I go about doing this?

I know that I probably have to use a background job on Parse, but how exactly do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you just want notifications when something new has been saved to a particular class or are you trying to display the most recent objects saved in a class?